# Create new instances with a condition

Tags: python, class, instance

I am trying to create instances from a dataset only if they have new `espn_player_id`. If there is a row that has already created as an instance, I just want to execute class method.

`td` means total data and it is `OrderedDict`.

> However, when it comes to else block, I keep getting an error,
>
> ```
> 'str' object has no attribute 'num_games'
> ```

How can I make `td[i]['espn_player_id']` be recognized as a name of existing instance to execute `num_games`?

```
class Player:
    QBR_h = None
    QBR_l = 0
    QBR_a = 0
    ap = 0
    ng = 0

    def __init__(self,pid,fname,lname):
        self.pid = pid
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        print(self.fname, self.lname,'Constructed')

    def num_games(self):
        self.ng = self.ng + 1
        print(self.fname,self.lname,'number of games:',self.ng)

    def max_QBR(self):
        if self.QBR_h == None or self.QBR_h < td[i]['total_QBR']:
            self.QBR_h = td[i]['total_QBR']
            print(self.QBR_h)

    def asdict(self):
        return {'fname':self.fname, 'ng':self.ng}

lst_pid = list()
for i in range(len(td)):
    print(td[i]['espn_player_id'])
    if td[i]['espn_player_id'] not in lst_pid:
        lst_pid.append(td[i]['espn_player_id'])
        print(lst_pid)
        td[i]['espn_player_id'] = Player(td[i]['espn_player_id'], td[i]['first_name'],td[i]['last_name'])
        td[i]['espn_player_id'].num_games()
        td[i]['espn_player_id'].max_QBR()
    else:
        td[i]['espn_player_id'].num_games()
        td[i]['espn_player_id'].max_QBR()
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but it appears that `td[i]['espn_player_id']` is a string (readability tip: please assign that to a variable inside the loop, since you reference it at least 7 times) - which in the `if` block you use to instantiate a `Player` object, but not in the `else` block. I'm not sure why you thought this string would be able to access those methods which will only exist on objects instantiated from the `Player` class (or a subclass).